Porting an exsiting Python Project to ROS2
I have a conceptual question about using ROS2 with other projects that I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer for.
I work with a few complete systems written in Python that are self-contained. I would like to integrate those systems into larger robotics applications (onboard control, real time autonomy, etc). My question is this: if I have a pre-existing, self-contained Python project, what is the "best practice" for integrating those systems with ROS-based systems? Should I just be writing interfaces between ROS2 and my existing projects, and launch them concurrently?
I have been able to get by so far by writing interface nodes and tacking them onto the pre-existing systems as necessary. It seems like a smoother integration would be to make ROS packages out of the pre-existing systems, but I've found that those systems require more refactoring than I would like to work as ROS packages, as that means that keeping them up to date with their development versions will require the same refactoring. This may be a result of my unfamiliarity with ROS2, and I'd be glad to be proven wrong.

I think it is good and standard practice to keep your ros independent libraries/modules separate from ros interfaces and packages. What you may want to have and think about is colcon integration. This way your python modules are getting "built" (more like configured) at the same time. I use ament_cmake_python, simply because I am used to it and everything is cmake'inized. But if I am not mistaken all you need is a setuptools like set-up and a configured package.xml for the python native package. Do ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python for a boiler plate.
